# What to use for Cross platform system tray application?

Tags: cross-platform, system-tray

I am sure there are multiple ways to get to what I want, but I would love it if you could share your experience with me. Since I am a student who just started.

I wanted to start a project that has a system tray icon as its core and I want to open some windows (for settings etc) I have done something like this before in c# using the Windows form application template.
But I am wondering, if there maybe is a way of doing that, so that I cloud not only compile it for Windows but also for Linux or Mac OS (also other languages like C or Python...).

While trying to search that, I came across something called Qt framework, and then I got confused, so if there is already a discussion around that, which I didn't find, I would be more than happy to be pointed to it.

If not, I want to know what you would advise me.

I need the project for Windows, is it worth the difficulty (if there is any) to go cross platform in a project?
Would there be any trade offs ?
Or is there a easy way, that is open sources, because I couldn't figure out if I would need to pay for this Qt?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: This question doesn't really have an "answer" but another alternative you might want to consider is Xojo. it has built-in support for Windows system tray icons and also makes native cross-platform desktop apps. http://www.xojo.com